# Pass XML data as parameter in a function call

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

I'm copying the `MyApp.exe.config` file to a separate location as an xml.

I'm using this custom config file to access and changes some settings when the application is running, rather than using the `ConfigurationManager.<section>` to modify the `app.config`.

The problem is, the default app.config file might be updated at later stage on the user machine and I want to propagate these changes back to my custom config file.

What is the best way to do this?

```
<configSections>
    <section name="" type="" />
</configSections>

<appSettings>
    <add key="" value="" />
</appSettings>

<ConnectionManangerProviders>
    <provider name="" enabled="" type="">
        <pollingInterval></pollingInterval>
    </provider>
</ConnectionManagerProviders>

<QueueManagerProviders>
    <provider name="" enabled="" type="unique" encrypted="" signed="" cryptoProvider="" />
    <provider name="" enabled="" type="unique" encrypted="" signed="" cryptoProvider="">
        <queueName></queueName>
    </provider>
    <provider name="" enabled="" type="unique" encrypted="" signed="" cryptoProvider="">
        <applicationName></applicationName>
        <connectionString></connectionString>
    </provider>
</QueueManagerProviders>
```

For example, this is how the configuration file looks. Let's say one of the values of the element under `<QueueManagerProviders>` is modified in the app.config, how can I pass the data in this file to a method so that the method can effectively parse through it and update the appropriate section in the custom config file that I created?

Comment: So you want to read this config file at run time (if it is changed)?

Comment: Yes. One of the services pushes updates to the config file from the server. I want to get these updated settings in my custom config file too.

Comment: Have you looked at System.Xml? Seems like you want to use XmlDocument at the very least

Comment: I've looked at LINQ to XML (XDocument), but was wondering if there is any better way to do this.

Comment: Are the structures of the two documents well defined? Then maybe you can use an XSL transformation (transforming one XML into another)

Answer (score 0):

This screams something about bad design, there are probably better ways to implement the whole functionality. But, if you are not in control of the "Services" part then you are stuck...

You probably need [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) which "Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes."

Add an event handler and, if your file changes, read the whole file again and parse it.

Comment: I understand. But my issues is not with detecting the change event, but rather gathering the data in the xml in an appropriate data structure(?) and pass it to a method that updates the custom config file.
I don't want to overwrite the whole file (custom config), but rather reflect the changes made to app.config.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom ConfigSection Handler (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3(v=vs.100).aspx).